# How to integrate Quickbooks API to custom salesforce through Apex code using REST API?

Tags: integration

I dont have any idea about quick books.Just i want to integrate salesforce with quick books using whatever apis or webservices.

This Quickbooks API is used to integrate the Quickbooks Online and Salesforce through a custom Apex code and not to depend on any other third-party tool

Any one can u please help me.

Comment: Be more specific. What do you want to do? Make QB insert/update data on Salesforce, the opposite, or both?

You can (and should) refer to the [QB API documentation][1] to learn which endpoints you need to call from Salesforce to update data on Quickbooks. The opposite is also truth: you should look into Salesforce's REST API on how to update data.


  [1]: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting

Comment: Have you started exploring Quickbook api's? Are you stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You have two routes: spend money on an existing integration, or spend time and build your own integration using the freely available API's.

Here's Salesforce's developer documentation, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/

And here's QuickBooks Online API documentation,
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting

With the information contained on those two sites, and in a couple hundred hours, you might have a working integration.

(if a couple hundreds hours seems like a lot, our integration, [Breadwinner](https://breadwinner.com/), which connects Salesforce to Xero & QuickBooks Online, has taken a total of 25 developer years so far to build)

If you need further help on StackExchange, you'll need to describe the specific technical problem you're having, otherwise you'll risk your question being "Closed as too broad".

Comment: Beat me to it lol. Is a developer year / 7 to convert to human years?